# SQL select dates in future and not ending before until date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select shows that are only in the future but also shows are are currently in progress. This must be a common request but I couldn't find any info on helping me solve this problem.

My tables has date columns:
- show_from
- show_until

```
SELECT * FROM shows s 
       WHERE s.show_status = 'ENABLED'
       AND s.show_from >= CURRENT_DATE()
       ORDER BY s.show_from ASC
```

This selects the shows in the future but if a show last for more than 1 day it will not be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM shows s 
WHERE s.show_status = 'ENABLED'
AND 
(
  s.show_from >= CURRENT_DATE() 
  OR (s.show_from <= CURRENT_DATE() AND s.show_until >= CURRENT_DATE())
)
ORDER BY s.show_from ASC
```

To select shows that have started but not yet finished.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 SELECT * FROM shows s 
   WHERE s.show_status = 'ENABLED'
   AND s.show_to >= CURRENT_DATE())
   ORDER BY s.show_from ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT * FROM shows s 
   WHERE s.show_status = 'ENABLED'
   AND (s.show_from >= CURRENT_DATE() OR s.show_to >= CURRENT_DATE())
   ORDER BY s.show_from ASC
```